# Tomar los dos últimos números y solo quedarme con los que terminen en 30 y 70 (C#)

Tags: c#

tengo un problema y es que no sé como tomar los últimos dos números y especificarle que solo quiero que me dibuje una línea si el número termina en 30 y en 70.

La siguiente línea lo explica mucho mejor:

```
Draw.HorizontalLine(this, "tag1"+ CurrentBar, 1000, Brushes.Blue);
```

Donde dice 1000 iría el número en el que yo quiero que se dibuje la línea horizontal. En mi caso quiero que dibuje una línea horizontal cada vez que aquél número termine en 30 y en 70. Ese número es un valor double que hacer referencia al precio de una acción, yo quiero que esa línea se dibuje cada vez que la acción se encuentre, por ejemplo, en 14.570,00 o en 12.330,00. Como ven no me importa lo que haya después del 30 o del 70, solo me interesa que sea un número cualquiera pero que termine con esas cifras.

Pensé en hacer un ciclo for donde cada vez que el precio termine en esos dos números, entonces dibuje una línea, pero no he sido capaz de conseguirlo porque no doy con la función correcta.

Desde ya, muchas gracias y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Y tu sabes como pintar la linea?

Comment: Si, ya tengo la función creada, solo necesito lo que he dicho

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = Math.Truncate(numero);

modulo = num % 100;

if (modulo == 30 || modulo == 70)
{
   //Dibujar línea
}
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es primeramente usar la **función Truncate** para quedarnos con la parte entera del número, y posteriormente calculamos el módulo del número truncado entre **100** para obtener los dos últimos dígitos, una vez hecho esto entonces preguntamos si el resultado de ese módulo es **30** o **70**, y de serlo pues dibujamos la línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió!

Comment: @MEVG si la respuesta te fue útil y resolvió tu problema seria bueno que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias